# Convert Wordpress post meta to PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I have a Wordpress post meta to MySql like

```
[{"field":"Email:1","title":"email","explanation_text":"","explanation_text_location":"","html_styling":"","text_to_display":"","show_title_field":"","pdf_file":"","pdf_file_button_styling":"","pdf_file_button_text":""}]
```

I need to convert it to a `PHP` array. I used following code to make it as an array.

```
$wpaf_field_title = maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta(52, '__wpaf_field_title', true));
print_r(json_encode($wpaf_field_title));
```

But it returns me

```
"[{\"field\":\"Email:1\",\"title\":\"email\",\"explanation_text\":\"\",\"explanation_text_location\":\"\",\"html_styling\":\"\",\"text_to_display\":\"\",\"show_title_field\":\"\",\"pdf_file\":\"\",\"pdf_file_button_styling\":\"\",\"pdf_file_button_text\":\"\"}]"
```

Comment: use json_decode instead of json_encode

Comment: @user3384985 data is not the type of serialize it `json_encode` you need to use `json_decode`.

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments you have to use json_decode() function:

```
$json = '[{"field":"Email:1","title":"email","explanation_text":"","explanation_text_location":"","html_styling":"","text_to_display":"","show_title_field":"","pdf_file":"","pdf_file_button_styling":"","pdf_file_button_text":""}]';
$data = json_decode( $json );
var_dump( $data );
```

And then you get:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (10) {
    ["field"]=>
    string(7) "Email:1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "email"
    ["explanation_text"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["explanation_text_location"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["html_styling"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["text_to_display"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["show_title_field"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pdf_file"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pdf_file_button_styling"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pdf_file_button_text"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```